# Material that doesn't actually hang (Training)

Tags: tactics, training, reference-request

(One of) My chess kiddie (U8!) is an aspiring grandmaster (I would lean that much out of the window), but we are just a small club. Still, I'm a life long chess kiddie trainer and want to give him the appropriate training to keep him from running away to the local big club as long as possible.

Methinks he plays a bit greedy. Maybe a good trait on his age level where his opponents hang pieces left and right, but I want to give him some training material "Think before you grab". A typical tactic from this area is the "Bxh2, g3, oopsie" manouvre,  even Fischer fell for that. Or the Qxb2-and-you-get-disowned.

Can you give me a reference specialized to this theme, be it book or online?
(For example, I'm thinking of the chapter "Greed" in Rowson's "7 Deadly Sins" book.)

EDIT: Here is an example I made myself, devoted to LxB-and-gets-jailed.
[image: 6 tactics]

Comment: What's actually the question here?

Comment: The sentence with the question mark...oopsie, got none :-) Edited for clarity.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HPNjK9ADvA Does this go in the right direction?

Comment: To better fit the format of this site, I'd suggest removing the first paragraph altogether and reworking the first part of the second paragraph to focus on the question.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Consider honouring the superiority of my reply - decisive results are very trendy these days!

Answer (score 2):

To "*keep him from running away to the local big club as long as possible*" is morally wrong.

Forwarding him to another learning environment is **not** an oopsie Bxh2 and g3 wins your student. Such a view is wrong.

It is instead much better to see yourself as "*the material that doesn't hang*".

Ask yourself, are you material that doesn't actually hang? Will a "*life long chess trainer*" still be there for him, should this student leave for another club?

"*Think before you grab!*"

By all means, support him joining and enjoying as many training opportunities as he likes, support his family, offer to cooperate with all his agents, find solutions that are designed to help his case, etc, over years. This is where you shine. Granting motivation and options. No laudations in return.

You just continue to not hang.

As for referrence, indeed, the chapter "Greed" in Rowson's "7 Deadly Sins".

Answer (score 0):

You could create any puzzle that lures a piece (rook?) away to back-rank mate.
Similarly, you could also create one that, if taken, loses protection for any other piece in the Mid-game and Opening. This could lead to thinking before taking any piece at all.

Make sure you play a few games with him to create this type of situation, and see if this is actually *applied* to any chess games they play.

This is an example (FEN):

```
1r4k1/5ppp/8/8/4B3/4R1P1/5P1P/6K1 w - - 0 1
```

https://lichess.org/editor/1r4k1/5ppp/8/8/4B3/4R1P1/5P1P/6K1_w_-_-_0_1?color=black

White does Bb7. If Rook Takes Rxb7, white can back-rank mate with Re8, and loses the win of 7 points.

```
2kr2nr/ppp3pp/q4pb1/3P4/5n2/NNQ2B2/PPP2PPP/R3R1K1 w - - 0 1
```

https://lichess.org/editor/2kr2nr/ppp3pp/qb3pb1/8/4Bn2/NNQ1P3/PPP3PP/R3R1K1_w_-_-_0_1?color=black

In this puzzle, White plays Nc5, attacking the queen at a6.
Black plays Rd1. It seems like Black is giving a free rook.
If Rxd1 happens, Black will do Ne2+, forking a king and queen. After taking the queen Nxc3, the checkmate threat will be ended.